# How do I work with adding things to files?

Tags: java, file

So, I'm back again with yet another problem. ^_^

This time, I'm working with a file management system in which I add the user's username and password when they enter it in the login screen window (not shown here. I want to write to a text file that stores the data on two seperate lines, but I don't know how to work it.

```
    File termsOfAgreement = new File(gamePath + "/terms.txt");

    try {
        termsOfAgreement.createNewFile();
    } catch (IOException exc) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Cannot create files! :(","Alas, something went wrong!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        System.exit(0);
    }

    String pathway = termsOfAgreement.getPath();

    try {
        this.writeToFile(pathway, "username", "passcode");
    } catch (IOException exc) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Cannot work with files! :(","Alas, something went wrong!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        System.exit(0);
    }
}

public void writeToFile(String filePath, String username, String passcode) throws IOException {
    FileWriter filewriter = new FileWriter(filePath);
    BufferedWriter bufferedwriter = new BufferedWriter(filewriter);

    String[] credentials = {username, passcode};
    String writtenStuffs = "";

    for (String credit : credentials) {
        writtenStuffs += credit + "\n";
    }

    bufferedwriter.write(writtenStuffs);
    bufferedwriter.close();
 }
}
```

I made an array, but it didn't seem to help. I'm turning to Stack Overflow for help.

Thanks in advance,
:)

Comment: And the issue you're running into is...?

Comment: making emotions doesn't tell me what your question is...

Comment: It won't run nor add anything to the file.

Comment: BufferedWriter#newLine ....

Comment: @NapravSpecif. are you sure you are calling it?  when you step through the code in your debugger what do you see?  Do you see any error?  BTW You have a really complicated way of writing two lines, but it should still work.

Comment: Sorry, still kind of noobish in the programming world. When I run it, my window pops up and says "Cannot work with files", just like I asked it to if it couldn't work.

Comment: In addition to `"Alas, something went wrong!"` you probably want to print out the exception message, like `"Alas, something went wrong!\n" + exc`, to figure out what actually went wrong.

Comment: You could also log the stack trace from the exception. Also, your call to close() should be in a finally block. You might want to look up the Java 7 try-with-resources statement, which is useful when working with files.

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem:

```
public void writeToFile(String filePath, String username, String passcode) throws IOException {
   PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("the-file-name.txt", "UTF-8");
   writer.println(username + "\n" + passcode);
   writer.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try add \r\n at the end of a line?

```
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(
            new File("whateverthefilenameis.txt")));
writer.write(username + "\r\n");
//if \r is deleted you won't see line changed in windows notepad
writer.write(password + "\r\n");
writer.close();
```

and you can use a BufferedReader(FileReader(File "filename") readLine() method to read every line in the file "filename"

It works properly in my windows system.